# Using log4net over the internet securely

Tags: log4net, remoting

I'm looking into using log4net in my VB.NET WinForms applications and ASP.NET websites. I'd like to have log messages sent to a server across the internet to centralize my logs (right now I'm either logging locally for installed WinForms apps, or sending emails...lots of emails). I'd also like to encrypt the message in transit, to be decrypted on the log server.

How can I send encrypted log4net messages to a logging server?

I found this:

https://log4netremotelogging.codeplex.com/

But I'm not sure if this would work across the internet. I also have no idea how I would secure it. Is there an event I can hook into to encrypt the message with a public key?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I actually found code to use log4net with a webservice. This is much better since you can secure the web service with https relatively easily. Here's the code:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16906/LOG4NET-WebServiceAppender

My only complaint is how he relies on his own custom "framework" dll to accomplish this. I'd prefer a bare bones example for clarity.